# My sm.current (sm is object of WindowManager) doesn't appear to be working in Kivy

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy

I am making a basic diet app as part of my high school project. I am trying to navigate among screens by using an object of WindowManager class that inherits from ScreenManager. However on running the program, I simply get a blank screen.

Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import mysql.connector as ms
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

db = ms.connect(user="root", password="jayanti1909", host="localhost", database="DIETIFY")
cursor = db.cursor()


class HomePage(Screen):

    def log_in_btn(self):
        sm.current = "LogIn"

    def sign_up_btn(self):
        sm.current = "SignUp"


class LogIn(Screen):

    def go_back_btn(self):
        sm.current = "HomePage"


class SignUp(Screen):
    name_of_person = ObjectProperty(None)
    height_of_person = ObjectProperty(None)
    weight = ObjectProperty(None)
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    insert_query = ""
    record_tuple = ()

    def submit_btn(self):
        self.insert_query = "INSERT INTO UserDetails VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        if (self.name_of_person.text != ""
            and float(self.height_of_person.text) > 0
            and float(self.weight.text) > 0
            and self.username.text != ""
            and self.password.text != ""):
                while True:
                    try:
                        self.record_tuple = (self.name_of_person.text,
                                             float(self.height_of_person.text),
                                             float(self.weight.text),
                                             self.username.text,
                                             self.password.text)
                        cursor.execute(self.insert_query, self.record_tuple)
                        db.commit()
                        sm.current = "LogIn"
                        break
                    except:
                        invalid_sign_up()
                        self.username.text = ''
                        sm.current = "SignUp"
                self.reset()

    def go_back(self):
        sm.current = "HomePage"

    def reset(self):
        self.name.text = ""
        self.name_of_person.text = ""
        self.height_of_person.text = ""
        self.weight.text = ""
        self.username.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalid_sign_up():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                content=Label(text='Invalid credentials'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [HomePage(name="HomePage"), LogIn(name="LogIn"), SignUp(name="SignUp")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "HomePage"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv file:

```
<HomePage>:
name: "HomePage"
GridLayout:
    cols:1

    Label:
        text: "Welcome to Dietify"
        color : 1,0,0,0.7
        font_size : 60

    Button:
        font_size : 30
        id: btn_1
        height: 20
        background_color : 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.6
        text: "Sign Up"
        on_release:
            root.sign_up_btn()
    Button:
        id: btn_2
        font_size : 30
        background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.4
        text: "Login"
        on_release:
            root.log_in_btn()

<LogIn>:
    name: "LogIn"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release: root.go_back_btn()

<SignUp>:
    name : "SignUp"
    name_of_person : name_of_person
    height_of_person : height_of_person
    weight : weight
    username : username
    password : password
    GridLayout:
    cols : 1
    size : root.width, root.height

    GridLayout:
        cols : 2

        Label:
            background_color: 0,128,128,0.7
            text: "Name"
        TextInput:
            id : name_of_person
            multiline : False

        Label:
            background_color: 0,128,128,0.7
            text: "Height"
        TextInput:
            id : height_of_person
            multiline : "False"

        Label:
            background_color: 0,128,128,0.7
            text: "Weight"
        TextInput:
            id: weight
            multiline : "False"

        Label:
            background_color: 0,128,128,0.7
            text : "Username"
        TextInput:
            id: username
            multiline : False

        Label:
            background_color: 0,128,128,0.7
            text : "Password"
        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline : False
    Button:
        id: btn
        text : "Submit"
        background_color :0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.6
        color : 0,0,0,1
        on_release: root.submit_btn()
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release : root.go_back()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your python file, check the MyApp class again...
It should be:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```

Instead of:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
```

As the app is returning the .kv file(which it can't present in any way) instead of your screen...